# switch between row wise and normal column wise in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I was wondering how to switch between row wise and normal (column wise) in dplyr. For example, the below code works but it produces some red-colored logs like a warning. How could I do the "select" command in a normal style (not rowwise):

```
df <- tibble(id = 1:6, year1 = 15:10, year2 = 13:8, year3 = 30:35, year4 = 40:45)
df %>% rowwise() %>%  
mutate(output = list(isoreg(c_across(year1:year4))$yf)) %>%
tidyr::unnest_wider(output) %>%
select(., -starts_with("year"))
```

I think by easily switching between the mentioned modes the issue would be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a named output which avoids the warnings. One way to do that is by using `setNames`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%  
  mutate(output = list(setNames(isoreg(c_across(year1:year4))$yf, 
                       paste0('col', 1:4)))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_wider(output) %>%
  select(-starts_with('year'))


# A tibble: 6 x 5
#     id  col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    14    14    30    40
#2     2    13    13    31    41
#3     3    12    12    32    42
#4     4    11    11    33    43
#5     5    10    10    34    44
#6     6     9     9    35    45
```

Answer (score 0):

`rowwise()` actually groups your data. Therefore, `ungroup()` drops the rowwise behavior.

In general, always ungroup your data right after you did your grouped operation. Otherwise, your code becomes very prone to errors.

Comment: I add the ungroup() but it still gave me the red-ish warning like logs.

Comment: which warnings do you mean? the "new names..."?